# What is the dual space of the tensor product of U' and V'?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

I'm struggling with exercise 6 from section 26 of Halmos' "Finite-dimensional Vector Spaces". The book asks

> If $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, what is the dual space of $U' \otimes  V'$?

Halmos defines $U \otimes V$ as the dual space of the space of bilinear forms on $U \oplus V$ (where $U \oplus V$ is the space of pairs of form $(x, y)$ with $x\in U$ and $y \in V$).  Hence a literal interpretation of $U' \otimes V'$ is the double dual of the space of all bilinear forms on $U' \oplus V'$. But this interpretation does not take into account the fact that the spaces we are taking tensor product of (namely $U'$ and $V'$) are themselves dual of other spaces (namely $U$ and $V$). My question is is there a perhaps more natural interpretation of $U'\otimes V'$?

Comment: Maybe it could help that if $V$ is a vector space and $V'$ is its dual, then the double dual $V''$ is canonically isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: One can show that a basis $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ of $U$ dualizes to a basis $\hat u_1,\ldots, \hat u_n$ of $U'$. Do the same with a basis of $V$, and then argue that the collection of all elements $u_i\otimes v_j$ is linearly independent and spans $U'\otimes V'$. (This description doesn't work if $U$ or $V$ is infinite dimensional, since then $U'$ has strictly larger dimension than $U$ and similarly for $V$.)

Comment: The answer is that the dual space of $U'\otimes V'$ is (naturally isomorphic to) $U\otimes V$, but I don't think it's obvious from what Halmos has established at that point in the book.

Comment: You're right blargoner. I also think Halmos could've justified identifying naturally isomorphic subspaces as the same a bit more.